# Inplace modification of slices

Tags: pandas

What's the most efficient way to do something like this (which doesn't work since the argument to `replace` is a slice)?

```python
DF[DF.col == x].col.replace( ... , inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to do the assignment explicitly:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [13]: df.loc[df.a == 3, 'b'] = df.loc[df.a == 3, 'b'].replace({4: 7})

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  7
```

---

Another option is to use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), this may well be faster:

```
df.update(df.loc[df.a == 3, 'b'].replace({4: 7}))
```